# SQL Server: table size +4x size of the CSV. Why?

Tags: sql-server

I have imported a 2.5 MB CSV file into MS SQL Server 2014.

The file has 150,000 records, 9 columns and lots of nulls.

If I right click the table in SQL Server management studio and go to storage, I see that 'data space' is 11 MB.

The table has no primary keys, no indices, no constraints. Why would the storage space be more than 4 times that of the CSV file? I never expected the size to be the same, but I find such a large difference puzzling.

Comment: Indexes, reserved space, fixed size  string `CHAR(1000)` columns and so on ...

Comment: Share your table structure and `EXEC sp_spaceused  table_name`

Comment: This was actually just a test CSV file with some random data. I have been using it to test how various ETL tools guess data types when there are many nulls.CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Alteryx_test2](
 [row number] [bigint] NULL,
 [date1] [datetime] NULL,
 [date2] [datetime] NULL,
 [date3] [datetime] NULL,
 [float1] [float] NULL,
 [integer1] [float] NULL,
 [null_field] [datetime] NULL,
 [text1] [varchar](21) NULL,
 [text2] [varchar](24) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

Comment: exec sp_spaceused yields: reserved: 11,336 KB ; data: 11,328 KB

Comment: You have a lot of datetime columns. This uses 8 bytes even if the value is NULL. So you probably have to use a second table to stock the non null date and remove dates from the first table in order to save space.

Comment: It doesn't seem like the most efficient use of space! Luckily I have TBs of space available, and this was just a test, but, still...

Comment: SQL Server is concerned about efficient storage and retrieval, not space efficiency.

Comment: SQL Server does care about space efficiency as it can affect storage and retrieval efficiency. Consider how many page reads for fixed space nulls vs 4-bit nulls for the OP's schema. @Pythonista if you have Enterprise Edition you can try enabling compression. Row compression is great for the schema you described; nulls take up almost no space. If you're on standard edition, consider being more frugal with your data types. For example, use smalldatetime (4bytes) instead of datetime (8bytes) if possible or even just date (3bytes),